# Javascript: why setCustomValidaty doesn't show up on first submission but it does on the second?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to validate a login form but I cannot understand the reason why when I give a wrong input the message from setCustomValidation doesn't show up the first time I click on the submit button (actually input). However when I click on the same button a second time the error message appears as it should. Why is that?
Here's the code.

```js
function validate(){

            console.log("check validate()")
            
            var email = document.getElementById("email");
            var psw = document.getElementById("psw");
            const patt =  /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

            if (email.value=="" && psw.value==""){
                email.setCustomValidity("You need to insert email and password!");
                return false;
            }

            else if ( email.value==""){
                email.setCustomValidity("Insert your email address");
                return false;
            }

            
            else if (psw.value==""){
                psw.setCustomValidity("Insert password");
                return false;
            }

            else if ( !patt.test(email.value) ){
                email.setCustomValidity("This is not an email!");
                console.log("Subcase works");
                return false;
            }

        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="eng">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Game</h1>
        <div>
            <form onsubmit="return validate()" method="POST" action="login.php">
                <input id="email" type="text" placeholder="email">
                <input id="psw" type="password" placeholder="password">
                <input type="submit" id="login-btn" value="Accedi">
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, according to the [documentation for setCustomValidity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLObjectElement/setCustomValidity):

> You must call the reportValidity method on the same element or nothing will happen.

The reason it works the second time is because when the custom validity message is set, when the "submit" button is clicked again, the browser's [built-in form validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation#using_built-in_form_validation) takes over and blocks the submit. That is why you do not see the "`check validate()`" message in the console log on subsequent submits.

Therefore, merely adding something like `email.reportValidity()` after your `email.setCustomValidity` is **not** a solution because on subsequent submits, the submit event handler will not get called, because the form never gets submitted due to the non-null custom validity message. If you try this, you will see that you get the same error message even after filling out the email and password fields. To fix this, you can either add `novalidate` to the form to bypass the browser validation, or you can clear the custom validity message when the input changes using the input's `onchange` event.

Here is a working example by adding `novalidate` to the form and using `reportValidity()`.

```js
function validate(){

            console.log("check validate()")
            
            var email = document.getElementById("email");
            var psw = document.getElementById("psw");
            const patt =  /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

            if (email.value=="" && psw.value==""){
                email.setCustomValidity("You need to insert email and password!");
                email.reportValidity();
                return false;
            }

            else if ( email.value==""){
                email.setCustomValidity("Insert your email address");
                email.reportValidity();
                return false;
            }

            
            else if (psw.value==""){
                psw.setCustomValidity("Insert password");
                psw.reportValidity();
                return false;
            }

            else if ( !patt.test(email.value) ){
                email.setCustomValidity("This is not an email!");
                email.reportValidity();
                console.log("Subcase works");
                return false;
            }

        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="eng">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Game</h1>
        <div>
            <form onsubmit="return validate()" method="POST" action="login.php" novalidate>
                <input id="email" type="text" placeholder="email">
                <input id="psw" type="password" placeholder="password">
                <input type="submit" id="login-btn" value="Accedi">
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is a working example using the `onchange` event on the input fields and using `reportValidity()`. Notice in this case, the `onsubmit` handler is only called after the validity message has been cleared and not every time you click the submit button.

```js
function validate(){

            console.log("check validate()")
            
            var email = document.getElementById("email");
            var psw = document.getElementById("psw");
            const patt =  /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

            if (email.value=="" && psw.value==""){
                email.setCustomValidity("You need to insert email and password!");
                email.reportValidity();
                return false;
            }

            else if ( email.value==""){
                email.setCustomValidity("Insert your email address");
                email.reportValidity();
                return false;
            }

            
            else if (psw.value==""){
                psw.setCustomValidity("Insert password");
                psw.reportValidity();
                return false;
            }

            else if ( !patt.test(email.value) ){
                email.setCustomValidity("This is not an email!");
                email.reportValidity();
                console.log("Subcase works");
                return false;
            }

        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="eng">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Game</h1>
        <div>
            <form onsubmit="return validate()" method="POST" action="login.php">
                <input id="email" type="text" placeholder="email" onchange="event.target.setCustomValidity('')">
                <input id="psw" type="password" placeholder="password" onchange="event.target.setCustomValidity('')">
                <input type="submit" id="login-btn" value="Accedi">
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```